# Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine() FormatException

Tags: c#, console, readline

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Int32 a = 3;
            Int32 b = 5;

            a = Console.Read();

            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Int32 a_plus_b = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine("a + b =" + a_plus_b.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error message at the `ReadLine()` function:

> *FormatException was unhandled.*

What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe the string you are putting is not valid integer? Try reading data to variable and add some validation using `TryParse`

Comment: On which specific line gives this error and what is the values of this variables..

Comment: If I comment the "a =..." or the "b = ..." line then everything is ok.
The values are just simple numbers like 4 or 7.

Comment: Please share the input data?

Comment: I get the error at the "b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());" line

Comment: Like @KamilBudziewski sugested, try doing something like this to avoid crashes: `bool isInputANumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int inputNumber);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is just because **you pressing ENTER key after you type first number**.
Lets analyze your code. Your code reads the first symbol you entered to `a` variable that `Read()` function does. But when you press enter key `ReadLine()` function returns empty string and it is not correct format to convert it to integer.

I suggest you to use `ReadLine()` function to read both variables. So input should be `7->[enter]->5->[enter]`. Then you get `a + b = 12` as result.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Int32 a = 3;
    Int32 b = 5;

    a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Int32 a_plus_b = a + b;
    Console.WriteLine("a + b =" + a_plus_b.ToString());
}
```

Comment: YES, 

iput1: 5 [enter] --> I got an exception
input2: 56 [enter] ---> Everything is fine

Comment: What should I do, to avoid this?

Comment: the program will still get an error if the user will input a non numeric input.

Comment: @JRC Yes, but this is different question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the:

`b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

Inside a [try-catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) block.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Int32 a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Int32 b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("a + b = {0}", a + b);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: the return value of the ReadLine() is string. you have to convert it to Int32

Comment: Change "Int32 b = 5;" into string b = "5";

Comment: "a" is also declared as an Int32, you need to add the Convert.ToInt32 to your Console.Read method as well…

Comment: No, because the Console.Read() returns with Integer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to use try catch, so if someone puts in something wrong you can find out

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Int32 a = 3;
            Int32 b = 5;

            a = Console.Read();
            try
            {
                b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Int32 a_plus_b = a + b;
                Console.WriteLine("a + b =" + a_plus_b.ToString());
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                // Error handling, becuase the input couldn't be parsed to a integer.
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. 
input: 5
after I hit the enter button the program becomes completed, because it got an exception in the try block.

Comment: I prefer a tryParse rather than a tryCatch block

Comment: Yes Blackcat, that is the purpose of try, except. Because you can continue executing the normal code, you have to do some error handling. If it is a minor error and you want to continue, you should use tryParse as JRC says. So example if I write "q" in, and you just want to replace my value by 0, you could do a tryParse, if it fails then just set the value to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Int32 a = 3;
Int32 b = 5;

if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
{
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b))
    {
        Int32 a_plus_b = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("a + b =" + a_plus_b.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
         //error parsing second input
    }
}
else 
{
     //error parsing first input
}
```